# Xcode, resizing a custom cell with UItextview according to user input using swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I am currently making an app with plenty of similarities to the apple mail app. I have successfully been able to make a selfsizing tableview based on variable data using auto layout for my message details scene. I am struggling with the compose message table which uses 3 different cells. I am using a simple custom cell class with different cell identifiers depending on the row. The to and subject cells use a textfield and text label. These work as expected. The message body cell uses a UItextview. It wraps lines correctly but the cell does not expand when it reaches the bottom of the view. When the table is reloaded the cell expands to the correct size. However, when text is removed it will stay at the expanded size. I made a function that reloads the table when a new line is reached and repositions where the user left off typing as a work around. This is obviously not the right way to do this, but I have been struggling to find a better way. I cannot find where I am going wrong. I am guessing it is a problem with one of my constraints.

Constraints are as follows: Trailing space to superview, Leading Space to superview, Bottom space to superview, Top space to superview with all constants set to 0. Trailing and Leading relation is set to equal and bottom and Top space are set to greater or equal relation...

Any help is greatly appreciate as I am new to Xcode.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: "didChangeSize:",
        name: UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification,
        object: nil)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source




override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 3
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cellidentifier : String?

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

         cellidentifier = "tocell"
    }

    if indexPath.row == 1 {

         cellidentifier = "subjectcell"

    }

    if indexPath.row == 2 {

         cellidentifier = "bodycell"

    }

    let cell: composeTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellidentifier!) as composeTableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == 2 {

        cell.bodyfield.delegate = self
    }

    return cell

}
```

my custom cell is the following:

```
class composeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var bodyfield: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet var tofield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var subjectfield: UITextField!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

    }

    func configCellbody(myfieldtext: String) {

    bodyfield.font = UIFont.preferredFontForTextStyle(UIFontTextStyleBody)
        self.bodyfield.text = myfieldtext

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()

    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show some code.